# Datepicker not working on jQuery migration

Tags: datepicker

Can somebody help me with this?

I have datepicker working with older version of jQuery ie. jQuery 1.4

Working link:

```
    ....
    $(function()
    {
        $('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:'1996-01-01'});
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nhuchhe/5r3eX/

But this stops working after jQuery migration to jQuery 1.9 using migration plugin.

Not working link:

```
    ....
    $(function()
    {
        $('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:'1996-01-01'});
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nhuchhe/P98bw/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ve got to do is upgrade your datepicker.js to version 2. See the below link for its updated version.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/